# Testing for whitespace in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, whitespace

I've got some blank values in my table, and I can't seem to catch them in an IF statement.

I've tried

`IF @value = ''` and `if @value = NULL` and neither one catches the blank values. Is there any way to test whether or not a varchar is entirely whitespace?

AHA! Turns out I was testing for null wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compare with NULL, use the IS NULL keyword.

```
--Generic example:
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE SOME_FIELD IS NULL;

--Instead of    

SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE SOME_FIELD = NULL;
```

Comment: Or SET ANSI NULLS OFF - I'd prefer to follow the SQL-92 spec tho' and us IS NULL

Comment: Might be missing something, but this doesn't correct the way of testing for whitespace at all. It corrects the syntax of checking for null, but that is NOT what the question was asking.

Answer (score 13):

```
ltrim(rtrim(isNull(@value,''))) = ''
```

Answer (score 3):

if length(@value) = 0  or  @value is null

Comment: Trim is only necessary when measuring values input, where whitespace isn't wanted. Otherwise len() catches it all.

Answer (score 3):

```
(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Value))=''
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

where length(rtrim(ltrim(yourcolumnname))) = 0 OR yourcolumnname is null

Answer (score 2):

I just did some testing, and found out something interesting.
I used to write my queries like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE Val IS NOT NULL
AND LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(Val))) > 0
```

But, you don't actually need to check for null, all you need to do is check the length after trimming the value.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(Val))) > 0
```

This select weeds out nulls as well as any columns with just white space.

As it turns out, you don't need to trim the value because SQL Server ignores trailing whitespace, so all you actually need it this:
    SELECT *
    FROM TableA
    WHERE LEN(Val) > 0

Answer (score 2):

Rather then performing excessive string manipulation with `LTRIM` AND `RTRIM`, just search the  expression for the first "non-space".

```
SELECT
            *
    FROM
            [Table]
    WHERE
            COALESCE(PATINDEX('%[^ ]%', [Value]), 0) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have fields with multiple spaces ('   ') so you'll get better results if you trim that:

```
where ltrim(yourcolumnname) = ''
```